# Inheritance: 'super' object has no attribute

Tags: inheritance, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a factory that will create an object that uses instance variables from a parent class. Doesn't a parent class get initialized to create a child class?
I thought adding `super().__init__` in the child class' `__init__()` might fix it but it did not.

If instead of instance variables I used class variables in the parent class this error does not occur, but I don't want to share the data between child instances.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
class factory:

  @staticmethod
  def fact(type):

   if type is "A": return child_A()

   if type is "B": return child_B()

class parent:

  def __init__(self):
    self.attr1 = []
    self.attr2 = []

class child_A(parent):

  def __init__(self):
    self.data = [super().attr1, super().attr2]

class child_B(parent):

  def __init__(self):
    self.data = [super().attr1, super().attr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was close. The parent attributes get accessed by the child class with `self` rather than `super()`. The parent class must be instantiated first.

```
class factory:

  @staticmethod
  def fact(type):

  if type is "A": return child_A()

  if type is "B": return child_B()

class parent:

  def __init__(self):
    self.attr1 = []
    self.attr2 = []

class child_A(parent):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.data = [self.attr1, self.attr2]

class child_B(parent):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.data = [self.attr1, self.attr2]
```